# How can I compare coefficient values from two different count models based on the same variables?

Tags: count-data, poisson-regression, quasi-likelihood

I'm running two quasi-Poisson models with the exact same variables, but on samples from two different countries. I'm doing this because I'm particularly interested in seeing whether the relationship between my dependent variable and some of the independent variables is stronger or weaker in one country vs the other, while at the same time providing a complete picture for either country. I see that this can be done in normal regressions by standardizing everything, but to my knowledge (not a statistician) this can't be done in count models. Is there a specific test that I could apply to compare said coefficients?

Comment: Hi. I am not sure what you have considered thus far, but do you want to standardize your outcome? You could transform your counts into rates if that helps. Also, are these simple random samples from each country? Have you considered merging your data and interacting your explanatory factors with a region/country indicator(s)?

Comment: Hi Tom, haven't tried either of these options, but will do. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Thomas. I tried your solution and it helped. Now a reviewer is asking me to control for a potential endogeneity problem for one of my variables, just wondering if you have an idea of how to this in a negative binomial model?

Comment: I would need to know more details about your study. What type of variables do you have? Let me know by updating your question.